# Export Highchart to Excel using PHPExcel

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, phpexcel

I'm using codeigniter and some highchart on one report. And I need to export that report to excel using PHPExcel, but right now I still can't find any solution for this case

Is there's any information How To Export multiple highcharts on one excel file ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly export a chart from Highchart to Excel. I know 2 solutions:

1. Use the Highchart data to make a chart using PHPExcel.
2. Use same JSON to generate a Highchart chart and a chart generated by PHPExcel.

Anothe possibility is to export the Highchart chart as an image and then uploading that image to the server and add it to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Highcharts are not images, they are interactive charts rendered within your browser. These cannot be exported to Excel. See the documentation:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: So what I need to do is remake the chart on excel ?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed an option.

Comment: Is there's any option ? I have tried it but I got other problem. Excel seems not happy with my generated chart. It's always remove them..

Comment: So how are you creating the charts for Excel from your HighCharts chart?

Comment: Yes @MarkBaker. That's what I want to achieve. But there's more than 1 highcharts on 1 excel file

Comment: Um, so why is it a problem if there is more than one chart per file - [Examples/33chartcreate-multiple-charts.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/33chartcreate-multiple-charts.php)

Comment: Because sometimes people only giving example of exporting 1 chart per 1 file. Anyway, I will try to run the example code this morning. Thanks @MarkBaker

Comment: I can't use 'Excel2007' because it's giving error 500 @MarkBaker and when I change to 'Excel5' the file is saving, but not with the chart

Comment: Excel5 doesn't support charts, only Excel2007; but check the logs and try to find why you're getting a 500. The most likely causes are time or memory problems

Answer (score 0):

You can export Highchart as images. Visit https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Use : $("#highchartDiv").highcharts().exportChart();

There are multiple options available to export Chart. Can be one of 'image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'application/pdf', or 'image/svg+xml'

You can also easily export multiple charts in one excel file.